# Dynamically change a image URL based on a variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm currently displaying a circle graph in a project I'm working on. I'm wanting to update the circle chart by changing the image URL that is displayed, there are 100 unique images each representing one percentage point on the chart. The URLs are set up in such a fashion img/circleGraph/circleG-12.png  the number (in this case 12) being the percentage complete that the graph is showing. In JavaScript /jQuery how could I alter the URL that is displayed dynamically, based on a percentage I'm returned from the database?

This is a .Net MVC application that I'm working on, so the percentage complete is returning back to me in a Razor variable as a decimal.  I know I would have to multiply this variable by 100 in order to convert to a whole number and then set that as part of the URL, but am unsure on how to approach it.

Comment: `$('imageID').attr("src", "img/circleGraph/circleG-" + {%} + ".png");`

Comment: Are the URLs all unique like '/img/circleGraph/squareG_12.png', '/img/circleGraph/somethingElseF_12.png', etc etc?

Comment: The only unique portion of the file name is the number. Shmiddty that looks about right going to give it a run. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$("img").attr("src", "/img/circleGraph/circleG-" + Math.Round(number*100) + fileExtension);
```

where `number` is the number you are returned from the DB and `fileExtension` is the file extension of the image file (.jpg, .png, etc...) - thanks @Shmiddty for the reminder!

Comment: This is a lot like how I figured the implementation would go. Will mark answered once I run it, Thanks!

Comment: Hope it works for ya, if not then let me know and I'll try to help more. Thanks

Comment: I'm getting an error when I compile for trying to run this portion Math.round(@(plan.Progress) * 100) . The @(plan.Progress) is the variable holding the decimal value. It's .Net MVC razor script, not sure if your familiar with that or not.

Comment: Ok so I removed the @ symbol and am no longer getting the compilation error. One last question. I'm running this after the <img> is displayed. I have the src attribute of that image set to img/circleGraph/circleg-0.png  as a place holder. Could this cause any hiccups down the road?

Comment: And the answer is no haha just tested it all out, thanks for the help!

Comment: Apologies @Stavros_s, I wasn't able to check SO much yesterday. It looks like you were able to get it all sorted out though =)